# Virtual LEGO / Technics / Mindstorms simulation environments

Tags: technic, mindstorms, cad

I know that there are quite a few LEGO CADs floating around, but are there any physically correct simulation environments for models built with LEGO / Technic / Mindstorms parts, that would, for example, allow me to:

- simulate how far would a particular moving part would move / rotate / etc, until it collides with other part
- simulate gear links (ideally, with tolerances / precision / friction of plastic gears)
- get estimates of speeds / torques exerted by specific motors
- get estimates of battery power drain

So far I've found [Robot Virtual Worlds](http://www.robotvirtualworlds.com/), but it doesn't seem to allow construction of arbitrary environments and, what's more important, seem to simulate only a few preset robots. Also it seems to be pretty crude in terms of physics simulated. Anything else exists?

Comment: Robotic Virtual Worlds does support the building of your own environments through the "Level Builder" tool, but I don't believe it supports importing your own robots yet - although the [RobotC team were talking about it in 2013](http://www.robotc.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=5826&p=24000&hilit=model+importer).

Answer (score 7):

Recently I met with [TeamSim](https://www.virtualroboticstoolkit.com/features). Its possibilities are impressing:

- you can make own robot via LDD and export it to the program
- you cam make own mat (FLL, WRO, sumo mats are already available)
- you can program a robot via NXT-G

I have no chance to investigate this program in detail, but I think it's what you want.

Comment: Not sure how much control you would have over this, but just wanted to mention that the link given is dead

Comment: fixed the link.