# Is there a free EV3 simulator (virtual machine) for the Mac OS?

Tags: ev3, ev3-g, mac

I recently saw [this](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/virtual-lego-technics-mindstorms-simulation-environments) question on a virtual EV3 machine. From the video, I felt that this software will be great. However, I don't have the budget needed to buy a licence. Is there any alternative to this system?

Answer (score 2):

You could try TRIKstudio: https://trikset.com/en/products/trik-studio

This allows you to program a robot based on the LEGO EV3 setup, however while the application itself has English, French and Russian translations, most of the online help is only in Russian.

[image: Preferences | Robots | EV3]

Comment: Can you please expand this answer a little. Have you used the software? How well does it work? Any limitations?

Comment: I have used the software, but for other uses. As far as I know, you can program in it, and then debug it in 2D mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for free software, you can use the now abandoned [Microsoft Robotics Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29081). It has a virtual robot simulator. The project was shut down around the same time the EV3 was released, so I doubt that there is a virtual EV3. There is a virtual NXT though. And it is possible to create your own virtual robot models if you are willing to put a massive amount of time into it.

Also, this is Windows, software, so you will need Parallels or a VM to run on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/download-software/) what you're looking for? Actually, [this](http://itunes.apple.com/app/lego-mindstorms-3d-builder/id679003776?mt=8/%22this%22) might be closer. 
NOTE: The latter is only compatible with iphone/ipad, but it might be closer...Other than that, I'm not sure.